# find or create passing 2 variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, psql

i have a opponents model, and a team model, i want to be able to create opponents on the fly, and have them assigned to a team id

at present within my model i have, which is creating the opponent but with a null team_id

```
def opponent_name
    opponent.try(:name)
  end

  def opponent_name=(name)
    self.opponent = Opponent.find_or_create_by_name_and_team_id(name,self.team_id) if name.present?
  end
```

and in my view i am calling this method with the following

```
.row
        .columns.large-2
          = f.label :opponent_name, :class =>'left inline'
        .columns.large-4
          = f.text_field :opponent_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Opponent.order(:name).map(&:name)}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: it doesnt appear to be getting/passing the team_id variable

Comment: so what im trying to do is pass the current users team_id to the setter to ensure that an opponent called test for team A doesnt already exist, if it doesnt it should create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
def opponent_name=(name)
  self.opponent = Opponent.find_or_create_by_name_and_team_id(name,self.id) if name.present?
end
```

if this is a function in the `Team` model?

Comment: hi, sorry this is in an event model, where the team_id is present within the form that is being submitted

Comment: this was similar to what i ended up using though had self.team_id